# Access a file in Android has changed

Tags: android

I'm using a tablet with Android 6.0 and the program Setlist Helper. For a couple of years now I have included two lines of code to reference a file named slh.css. One is online at my personal website and the other is a downloaded copy of the file in case there is no internet connection. Both links worked until recently. The Internet website still works fine but if there is no Internet connection, I am no longer able to reach the locally stored copy of the file. This is the code I'm using. I do not have root access on this tablet. I contacted the developer and he sent me here.

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/slh.css"

Answer (score 0):

You have not attached the code. So I can't answer you for sure. But not so far I've done a similar program. Here is the code to open the file:

```
public void Archive(String selectedItem) {
        File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
        for (File f : listFile) {
            if (f.isDirectory() && (!f.getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(dir)))) {
                File[] listFile2 = f.listFiles();
                for (File f2 : listFile2) {
                    if (f2.getName().toUpperCase().contains("S")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Sales " + f2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will help you

Comment: Sorry, the code was there but it was hidden. I took it out of the angle brackets so it is now visible.